# hybrid adjectives and how to diagram

Tags: adjectives, diagramming

This query is a follow-up from another question I asked a few days ago. I am still pondering how to best interpret the following phrase grammatically:

"my brother's weapon"

Could I categorize it as follows:

my = Possessive pronoun adjective modifying brother's

brother's = possessive noun also functioning as an adjective modifying weapon

my brother's = adjective phrase collectively modifying weapon

If I diagrammed this, would "weapon" be on the main line with "brother's" descending on a slanted line below it like an adjective?  Would "my" be on another adjective line coming off of "brother's"?

I'm thinking the flow would be similar to the way one might diagram "the bright red truck"?  In this phrase, would you consider "bright" an adjective modifying "red" with the both of them working together as an adjective phrase modifying truck?

Thank you in advance for your polite feedback.  I'm working hard to clarify my understanding of how these parts of speech function together in context.

Comment: _My_ and _the_ are both determiners, not adjectives, and modify nouns independently of adjectives. Determiners appear before adjectives in noun phrases, and may or may not modify the noun phrase instead of the noun. Depends.

Comment: I'd like to see 'galore' diagrammed.

Comment: @Edwin: Let's just deal with the *whisky* first, and worry about the *galore* bit if we're still standing! :)

Comment: @FF That's cheating. The seeing-double classification.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your specific query about how to diagram "my brother's weapon," you would diagram "brother's" on a slanted line under "weapon" as "brother's" is a possessive that modifies "weapon." "My" would go on a line under "brother's" because "my" tells whose brother.

Comment: Right. One way or another, any structure that indicates this nested bracketing -- [[my brother's] weapon] -- is correct. As far as Reed-Kellogg is concerned, assuming _weapon_ is on the main line (head of direct object noun phrase, say), then _brother's_ would be a diagonal modifier (like an adjective), and _my_ would be a parallel diagonal modifier **under** _brother's_, with a right-angle modification connector to _brother's_, rather than _weapon_. (as well as I can describe it here, anyway)